# how to visualize Xsense imu data

Tags: ros, imu, imu-drivers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,

i am using xsense imu and when running mtnode.py i can see the change in orientation values but no change in velocity and acceleration both remains zero if i move the imu. what would be done extra to see these values.
Thanks

P.S i am using [xsens_driver package from ethzasl_xsens_driver stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ethzasl_xsens_driver) on ros electric.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47174/how-to-visualize-xsense-imu-data/) by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2012-10-31

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-10-31**:
I would help to add the package link you are using as there are multiple xsens drivers available.

**Comment by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on 2012-11-01**:
@dornhege i edited the question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible that your IMU is not configured to output those values. Take a look at the --output-mode option to mtdevice.py.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Configuring xsens_driver for XSENS IMU in ROS
Here I employ xsens MTI-G IMU which is orange in colour.

I am working in ROS FUERTE on ubuntu 12.04 using the xsens_driver package that ships in ethzasl_xsens_driver.

I tried to get all the relevant data from IMU namely
orientation
orientation covariance
angular velocity
angular velocity covariance
linear acceleration
linear acceleration covariance

Configuration steps

1. Attach IMU via USB
2. sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0
3. rosrun xsens_driver mtdevice.py --configure --output-mode=coapvs --output-settings=tqMAG

The above command should result in something like this
`Configuring mode and settings  Ok`

Running the driver

4. roslaunch xsens_driver xsens_driver.launch
5. rostopic echo /imu/data

Then it should display all the data from IMU

Good day!

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-03-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) on 2014-04-30**:
Hi, I also use an xsens MTI-G 700 on ubuntu 12.04. I use the xsens_driver from the hydro debs and have the problem, that the configuration call "rosrun xsens_driver mtdevice.py --configure --output-mode=coapvs --output-settings=tqMAG" causes both the mtdevice.py as well as the node to fail have parsing problems: "MT error: could not parse MTData message" does anybody have an idea? both work fine when I use: rosrun xsens_driver "mtdevice.py -c -s 0x1 -m 0x4"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To anyone with the same problem. I was able to make it work by using "rosrun xsens_driver mtdevice.py -l --output-mode=coapvs --output-settings=tqMAG". -l is a flag for legacy configuration.

---

Originally posted by [Iuri07](https://answers.ros.org/users/34026/iuri07/) with karma: 11 on 2018-03-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1